# Is it possible to add a new attribute to Core Data without having issues with users and their current data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, model

I want to add a new attribute to my Core Data model but I'm worried if I do the users data will no longer work, and they'll have to redownload the app. I've had issues before where I change it a bit (though through deletion) and it causes big issues with the app where I need to reinstall it.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is called Core Data Migration: Ray Wenderlich has a great tutorial on it [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration). If you are just adding a new attribute, it should be (relatively) simple to do an automatic/lightweight migration.

Comment: If you're just adding an attribute then you shouldn't have to write any code whatsoever. Just make sure both versions are in your schema and supply `@YES` for `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption`.

Comment: How do I change the corresponding .h and .m files that are part of the Core Data model to reflect the changes?

Comment: Just regenerate them by creating new NSManagedObjectSubclasses.